# What can I do when Text = NULL?

Tags: php, marquee

```
<marquee behavior="alternate" scrolldelay="1" scrollamount="2">
  <?php do { ?>
     <?php echo $row_Recordset1['Name']; ?>:&nbsp;
     <?php echo $row_Recordset1['Text']; ?>&nbsp;
     &#8226;
  <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</marquee>

<?php mysql_free_result($Recordset1); ?>
```

Comment: Not a real question? How so? Correct NULL value handling seems very real...

Comment: The [<marquee> element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/marquee) is non-standard and should not be used. The moving text is an accessibility hindrance and to put it bluntly: moving text is just plain annoying crap.

Comment: @EFraim I believe they're referring to the $row_Recordset1['Text'] in which case, if it's NULL, it could end up printing just a name and no following text. The question is about what to do then I guess...

Comment: @EFraim: The source code was improperly formatted, and therefore completely hidden when it was voted down. I cleaned it up... if I could take my close vote back, I would.

Comment: What happens now when `$row_Recordset1['Text']` is NULL?  Is it undesirable?  Why?  What do you want to have happen?

Answer (score 1):

Print a friendly message to the user instead of `NULL`:

```
<?php echo (NULL === $row_Recordset1['Text']) ? "No value" : $row_Recordset1['Text']; ?>&nbsp;
```

As xil3 illustrates, you can also use this pattern ([from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)):

```
// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

Comment: `($row_Recordset1['Text']!='NULL')` This is wrong! This is correct: `($row_Recordset1['Text']!==NULL)` See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it written right now, $row_Recordset1 will be null the first time it goes into the loop.

I've rewritten it for you:

```
<marquee behavior="alternate" scrolldelay="1" scrollamount="2">
  <?php while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) { ?>
     <?php echo (($row_Recordset1['Name'] != null) ? $row_Recordset1['Name'] : 'n/a'); ?>:&nbsp;
     <?php echo (($row_Recordset1['Text'] != null) ? $row_Recordset1['Text'] : 'n/a'); ?>&nbsp;
     &#8226;
  <?php } ?>
</marquee>

<?php mysql_free_result($Recordset1); ?>
```

Comment: sorry i mean in some Text fields are empty :)